# Slow socket response time when using multiple queries

Tags: python, postgresql, sockets, tcp, sqlalchemy

I am using a socket server which use `ThreadingMixIn` to make it non-blocking.The server is working well, it can handle hundreds of connection in the same time without any kind of problem. My problem is starting with the `SqlAlchemy` which help to query and update my database. After a client send a message (in every second) to my server, I have to make two query and one update in my database. The two query is very simple and the table is small, the update is more problematic, here I have to update by an Id (the table's Id is indexed in my database) and the table contains thousands of rows. The problem occurs when 200 client connect to my server, although my script is able to handle both read and write side, but after 200 connection connection idle and response time starting to slow down. I track it with `tcptrack` and I see that the average idle increase from 0-1 s to 2-3s. My queries and updates are fast, but **after 200 connection these queries slows down**. **I also measure the execution time in the code, and  I have noticed,  that `t1` increase to 2s a couple of times from avarage 0.005s.**  I attach my simplified code.

**My brief code example:**

```
from config_file import *
import os
import sys
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import socketserver
import select    
from models import Users, Model1, Model2
from base_db import Session, engine, Base, conn

class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def __init__(self, request, address, server):
        BaseHTTPRequestHandler.__init__(self, request, address, server)

    def do_GET(self):
        while True:
            readable, writable, exceptional = select.select([self.rfile], [self.wfile], [self.rfile, self.wfile])
            try:
                for s in readable:
                    s.readline()
                    try: 
                        t0 = time.time()
                        session = Session()
                        model_data_1 = session.query(Model1).filter_by(id=1)
                        model_data_2 = session.query(Model2).filter_by(foo=False).all()
                        session.query(Users).filter_by(id=111).update({'test1' : 21, 'test2': 0, 'test3': "FIX", "timstamp": datetime.datetime.utcnow() }) 
                        t1 = time.time() - t0
                    except:
                        session.rollback()
                    finally:
                        session.close()

                for s in writable:
                    session = Session()
                    try:
                         self.model_data_2 = session.query(Model2).filter_by(type="test").first()
                    except:
                        session.rollback()
                    finally:
                        session.close()
                    if self.model_data_2:
                        time.sleep(1)
                        s.write(self.model_data_2.data)
            except Exception as e:
                print (e)

class MyServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':  
    httpd = MyServer((HOST, PORT), MyHandler)
    try:
        httpd.allow_reuse_address = True
        httpd.serve_forever() 
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    httpd.server_close()
    conn.close()
```

**By database config:**

```
import sqlalchemy as db
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
from config_file import *

engine = db.create_engine("postgresql://" + DB_AUTH_USER +
                          ":" + DB_AUTH_PASSWD + "@" + DB_HOST_PORT + "/" + DB_NAME)
conn = engine.connect()
session_factory = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Session = scoped_session(session_factory)
Base = declarative_base()
```

**My question is why slows down the average execution time after 200 connection? My queries are fast but some reason it starting to slow, or my threads doing this slowdown? Thank you very much in advance!**

Comment: I have already tried to set  `pool_size ` to very large number too, but it didn't help me.

Comment: Slow *database* response time when using multiple queries.

Comment: Try using session.commit( ) after each update

Answer (score 0):

Finally I migrated from SqlAlchemy to  vanilla psycopg2, which eventually solved my problem.